# Hiding What Site You're On (Branding Issues)

Tags: language-agnostic

Here's the scenario:

I have a private site that, once logged on, will display different information depending on the attributes of your account:  the pages are branded differently based upon what company you are associated with.

The problem is the companies linking to this site want everything to be displayed as their own brand, and do not want to see my brand anywhere, especially in the URL (i.e. from www.theirbrand.com they do not want to have links to www.mybrand.com).

Is there an elegant solution to this?  Is the best option to add a page on www.theirbrand.com that contains an iframe with a source of www.mybrand.com (I'm not sure if that would interfere with back/forward navigation, etc), or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just adding a subdomain to their domain, pointing to your server?

Comment: Nice.  The only issue will be their need for a SSL certificate, but outside of that I like it.

Answer (score 0):

to solve a similar problem in asp.net, we used dynamically loaded master pages based on the url